# Best Ubuntu release for AMD Athlon 64 + 3000 1.8 GHz?

Tags: hardware

What is the best Ubuntu release for this hardware:

- AMD Athlon 64 3000+ 1.8 GHz
- 3 GB RAM
- ATI Radeon X1050 256MB

Because with Ubuntu 14.04 it crashes.

Comment: Your graphics card is supported by open source drivers in 14.04. It is no longer supported by the proprietary drivers, so make sure you have removed fglrx.

Comment: Is it possible is this the issue that crash the system? How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ubuntu 12.04 that has support until 2017.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/